# Laravel Sail Docker can't connect to database when migrating

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker

I'm migrating my Laravel 10 project over to Sail. I'm running on Windows 10 and have WSL installed. Everything is working apart from connecting to the database. I keep getting:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = domainmonitor_db and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

I can login via PHPmyadmin using the username sail and password password, but if i try to manually create a database through there I also get:

> #1044 - Access denied for user 'sail'@'%' to database 'domainmonitor1_db'

Here's my `.env` setup for database

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3307
FORWARD_DB_PORT=3307
DB_DATABASE=domainmonitor_db
DB_USERNAME=sail
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

I have tried changing `DB_HOST` to many variant such as 127.0.0.1, host.docker.internal, localhost, nothing seems to work. What am I missing?

```
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.1
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
                NODE_VERSION: '18'
        image: sail-8.1/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
            - '${VITE_PORT:-5173}:${VITE_PORT:-5173}'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
            IGNITION_LOCAL_SITES_PATH: '${PWD}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mailpit
            - phpmyadmin
            - mysql
    mailpit:
        image: 'axllent/mailpit:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MAILPIT_PORT:-1025}:1025'
            - '${FORWARD_MAILPIT_DASHBOARD_PORT:-8025}:8025'
        networks:
            - sail
    phpmyadmin:
        image: 'phpmyadmin:latest'
        ports:
            - '8080:80'
        networks:
            - sail
        links:
            - mysql
        environment:
            - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:5.7'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3307}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
            - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test:
                - CMD
                - mysqladmin
                - ping
                - '-p${DB_PASSWORD}'
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-mysql:
        driver: local
```

Answer (score 0):

Your

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = domainmonitor_db and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

strongly suggests that you have `domainmonitor_db` without the quotes being generated into the query.

> "I can login via PHPmyadmin using the username sail and password password, but if i try to manually create a database through there I also get:"

> #1044 - Access denied for user 'sail'@'%' to database 'domainmonitor1_db'

Your `sail` user therefore has not enough privileges. You will therefore need to log in with a user that actually has the privileges you need (`root` ?) and either do this db creation with this privileged user and grant some privileges to `sail`, or grant privileges to `sail` and then reconnect with `sail` and try again.

Look at the

```
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
```

settings in your Docker and find out what user is it really referring to, because if it's a user with higher privilege, then you will need to find out where and how the variables involved above are defined.

Comment: What are you suggesting? I just tried granting all permissions to sail as root through phpmyadmin. Still no luck

Comment: @RyanH if you run `select user, host from mysql.user where user = 'sail';` what do you see as a result?

Comment: I see a user called "sail" and the host is "%".

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
container_name: mysql
```

in the mysql service inside docker-compose.
Also when you connect your application with the container name of database you should use the internal port of the container i.e. 3306.